# why do we use json JSON.createGenerator

Tags: jsongenerator

I have a code `JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);` 
I am not exactly getting an understanding of this line.

The next lines use

```
 gen.writeStartObject();
 gen.writeStringField('tName', TMsg);
```

Answer (score 3):

I find that `JSONGenerator` is rarely needed. To generate or parse JSON, using the `serialize` or `deserialize` methods of the [JSON](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm) class directly is usually the best way to go to generate valid JSON or parse JSON.

If you want data holder classes generated, also consider using https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/.

Methods like your `writeStringField` will ensure that a double quote embedded in the string will be correctly escaped so it is not mistaken for the end of the JSON string. The `serialize` methods do that too.

Comment: Thanks a lot Keith . JsonGenerator was used by us to create a response message in json format

Answer (score 1):

Using the **JSONGenerator** class methods, you can generate standard JSON-encoded content.

You can construct JSON content, element by element, using the standard JSON encoding. To do so, we have to the methods in the JSONGenerator class.

```
writeStartObject()
    
    Writes the starting marker of a JSON object ('{').

writeStringField(fieldName, stringValue)

    Writes a field name and value pair using the specified field name and string value
```